# Is it safe to use TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY?

Tags: android, android-service, overlay, android-windowmanager

I am using [`TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY) in an application where it doesn't need to take any touch events. It is added via `Service` and will be removed after some time when the application is closed.

Is it safe to use `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` (security wise, Android API version support, future support, etc)? Or, do I have to use `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`?